# Mocking docblock annotations in PHPUnit

Tags: annotations, phpunit, docblocks

I am building an app that implements custom docblock annotations using the Doctrine Annotations library.

For PHPUnit testing, is it possible to create a mocked class that has mock docblocks?

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390001/3207129), I learned how to mock a class, like so:

```
$foo = $this->getMockBuilder('nonexistant')
    ->setMockClassName('TestClass')
    ->getMock();
```

Is there a way to mock a docblock? Building on the class example, Something like this is what I imagine:

```
$foo = $this->getMockBuilder('nonexistant')
    ->setMockClassName('TestClass')
    ->setMockClassDocblock('/** @SomeAnnotation("foo") */')
    ->getMock();
```

If not - is there anything I can do besides just creating actual test classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to mock a docblock. If you can make the case that there should be then please open a [ticket](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/new).